# C# EF Core build dynamic select statement with expression tree

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I want to dynamically create a select statement that creates an array of objects through an array initializer. Those initializers are taken from a provided list of property expressions.

In this example we want to list just the 'Component' property of an entity called 'topic'.

This is how the select statement should look like:

```
Query.Select(topic => new object[] { topic.Component });
```

And here is how I create that expression dynamically:

```
// an example expression to be used. We only need its body: topic.Component
Expression<Func<Topic, object>> providedExpression = topic => topic.Component;
            
// a list of the initializers: new object[] { expression 1, expression 2, ..}. We only use the example expression here
List<Expression> initializers = new List<Expression>() { providedExpression.Body };
            
// the expression: new object[] {...} 
NewArrayExpression newArrayExpression = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), initializers);

// the expression topic => 
var topicParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Topic), "topic"); 
            
// the full expression  topic => new object[] { ... };
Expression<Func<Topic, object[]>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Topic, object[]>>(newArrayExpression, topicParam);

// pass the expression
Query.Select(lambda);
```

Now, the created expression looks exactly like the example above, but EF Core throws the good old

`The LINQ expression 'topic' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly...`

But even from the debugger (see image), the (working) example expression and the generated one are **identical**. Where does the magic happen that I don't understand?
Any tips?

[Generated and example expression in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJF2T.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated and example expressions may *look* identical in the debugger, but they actually aren’t. The problem is that your `lambda` expression references *two* ParameterExpression objects, both named `topic`:

1. The first is created implicitly by the C# compiler when it converts `topic => topic.Component` to an Expression.
2. The second, `topicParam`, is created explicitly.

Even though the two ParameterExpression objects have identical names, they’re treated as distinct parameters. To fix the code, you must ensure that the *same* ParameterExpression object is used in both the parameter list and body of the `lambda`:

```
var topicParam = providedExpression.Parameters[0]; // instead of Expression.Parameter
```

However, if you have multiple provided expressions, then the C# compiler will generate multiple `topic` ParameterExpression objects, so this simple fix won’t work. Instead, you will need to replace the auto-generated `topic` parameter in each `providedExpression` with your explicitly created ParameterExpression:

```
public class ParameterSubstituter : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _substituteExpression;

    public ParameterSubstituter(ParameterExpression substituteExpression)
    {
        _substituteExpression = substituteExpression;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return _substituteExpression;
    }
}
```

And in your method:

```
var topicParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Topic), "topic");
List<Expression> initializers =
    new List<Expression>
    {
        new ParameterSubstituter(topicParam).Visit(providedExpression.Body)
    };
NewArrayExpression newArrayExpression = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), initializers);
Expression<Func<Topic, object[]>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Topic, object[]>>(newArrayExpression, topicParam);
```

Comment: Great piece of code that helped me to solve a similar problem in my application! Is it possible to adapt the code to generate an anonymous type "on-the-fly" instead of the object[] array? The query should look like this : Query.Select(topic => new { topic.Component1, topic.Component2, topic.Component3 });  instead of Query.Select(topic => new object[] { topic.Component1, topic.Component2, topic.Component3 });

Comment: @RickyTad: You can use Reflection Emit to generate dynamic types, but I don't know whether dynamic types work with LINQ expressions.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will look after some examples with Reflection Emit. What about using a DTO class instead of the object[]? How can the code be adapted to have something like Query.Select(topic => new TopicDTO { Comp1=topic.Component1, Comp2=topic.Component2, Comp3=topic.Component3 });  TopicDTO is a class, something like class TopicDTO {  public int Comp1 { get; set; }   public int Comp2 { get; set; }   public int Comp3 { get; set; } }

Comment: @RickyTad: Use [Expression.MemberInit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.memberinit) instead of Expression.NewArrayInit.

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet? Actual code: if (addComp1)
{
Expression<Func<Topic, object>> comp1Expr = topic => topic.Comp1;
initializers.Add(new ParameterSubstituter(topicExprParam).Visit(comp1Expr.Body));
}
if (addComp2)
{
Expression<Func<Topic, object>> comp2Expr = topic => topic.Comp2;
initializers.Add(new ParameterSubstituter(topicExprParam).Visit(comp2Expr.Body));
}
...
NewArrayExpression newArrExpr = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), initializers);
Expression<Func<Topic, object[]>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Topic, object[]>>(newArrayExpr, topicExprParam);

Comment: @RickyTad: Please post a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76894950/ef-core-6-dynamically-create-linq-expression-for-choosing-columns-in-select-sta